# Radius of the Earth at N32.704220, W90.000000?

Tags: spherical-coordinates, geodesy

I want to express a point on a map in radian spherical coordinates. By Google maps, this location is north of Canton, MS, USA just a few hundred feet from US 51.

In radian spherical coordinates, $(?,-\pi/2,1) = (?, 3\tau/4,1)$. The first one is radius of Earth, the second is radians east, and the third is the angle from N. Pole.

In other words, how to describe the radius at the point which is $-\pi/2$ or $3\tau/4$ is 90 degrees west. And with the angle from North Pole as 1 or $(\pi/2-1)$rad north = $(\tau/4 -1)$ rad north which is 32.7042204869 degrees N.

I know the Earth is not a sphere, but nearly spherical. I also know that the equator had one radius and the north pole another. Which means that the radius at this location is in between these two radii. Which of the two should be used as radius = 1? With the north radian measure, being at 1, does that mean it is using radius = 1 of the pole, equator, or what is at the questioned location?

Comment: This is a question for geologist, not mathematicians unless you specify a model for the earth, e.g. the earth is modelled as an ellipsoid with specifications $\ldots$.

Comment: Try asking this on gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

> With the north radian measure, being at 1, does that mean it is using radius = 1 of the pole, equator, or what is at the questioned location?

A one-line answer is: "None of the above."

A slightly more detailed answer is that the assumption that the north radian
measure of this point is $1$ is inconsistent with the Earth being a
spheroid with significant positive flattening.

A good reference is http://williams.best.vwh.net/ellipsoid/ellipsoid.html.

The gist of this is that if you assume a spheroidal but non-spherical Earth,
with a polar radius less than its equatorial radius,
the point with geodetic coordinates
N$32.704220$, W$90.000000$
will be at an angle greater than $57.29578$ degrees from the north pole
in spherical coordinates.
The angle in spherical coordinates is $\angle POC = \pi/2 - \angle POD$
in the figure below (from http://williams.best.vwh.net/ellipsoid/node1.html),
which is greater than $\pi/2-\angle P'OD = \pi/2 - \theta$,
which in turn is greater than $\pi/2 - \phi$,
assuming that $\phi$ is your north coordinate converted to radians.

[image]

If the equatorial radius is $a$ and the polar radius is $b$,
then the angles $\phi$ and $\theta$ in the figure are related by the equation

$$\tan\theta = \frac ba \tan\phi.$$

Having used this to find $\theta$, we find the radius, $|OP|$, as follows:

$$|OP| = \sqrt{|OD|^2 + |DP|^2} = \sqrt{a^2 \cos^2\theta + b^2 \sin^2\theta}.$$

To find the correct third coordinate in spherical coordinates,
namely, $\angle POC$, we use

$$\cot\angle POC = \frac ba \tan\theta = \frac{b^2}{a^2} \tan\phi.$$

If the original source of this question expected the third coordinate of
the spherical triple to be $1$, then either they were expecting you to
assume a spherical Earth after all, or they were misinformed about the
nature of geodetic coordinates on the actual Earth.

Comment: +1 Interesting. If I understand correctly,  the usual ( longitude, latitude ) of a place specify the direction of corresponding normal vector on earth's reference ellipsoid. right?

Comment: @achillehui That is what my sources say. Equivalently, in the northern hemisphere, north latitude is the elevation of the celestial north pole above the horizon (and a similar rule applies if you change "north" to "south").

Comment: Thanks, learn a new thing every day.

Comment: I guess I am still confused. I am looking at the diagram at the point intersecting the red line with the ellipse, call it P". It seems to me that this is what a GPS ellipsoid would be using as the location at question or something nearby (maybe the intersection of the tangent line above P"?). If I am correct, then how does this change things? Also, I don't think the line with $\phi$ is a plumb line by gravity, am I correct?

Comment: @JohnNicholson The line at angle $\phi$ is the plumb line at the point where it intersects the surface: otherwise the surface of the ellipsoid would  be sloped with respect to the plumb line, all the waters of the oceans at that latitude would run down that slope, and mean sea level would end up at a different surface. Of course, the "force of gravity" that determines the plumb line at that point is a combination of gravitational attraction due to the Earth's mass and the centrifugal force observed in the rotating frame attached to the Earth at that point.

Comment: As for what a GPS uses as coordinates, it can use whatever its designers want internally, but the latitude of Canton, MS is defined on the USGS maps in the way I described, and I doubt Google Maps or a GPS would deliberately show it at different geodetic coordinates in the user interface.